# jQuery "filter" not updating after items removed

Tags: jquery, filter

I am having a problem with jQuery's .filter method.  My code is as follows (heavily stripped of not relevant bits).

```
(function($) {
    $.ticker = function( el, options ) {
        // to avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        var o, base = this;

        base.el = el;
        base.$el = $(el);

        base.init = function() {
            base.options = o = $.extend( {}, $.ticker.defaultOptions, options );
            base.$items = base.$el.find(' ul > li');
            base.timer = null;

            base.startTimer();
        }

        base.animate = function( ) {
            base.$items.filter(':eq(0)').appendTo(base.$el.find('ul'));
        }

        // initialise the object
        base.init();
    };

    $.ticker.defaultOptions = {
        delay: 2000,
        transitionSpeed: 700
    }

    $.fn.ticker = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            (new $.ticker(this, options))
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

What I would expect this to do, is every 2 seconds, the "base.animate" function would move the first LI item from the top to the bottom of the UL tag.  This works the first time, but for subsequent iterations, the *last* LI item (which used to be first) is moved to the end of the UL tag instead.  It seems the **.filter(':eq(0)')** is constantly referring to what used to be the first item, rather than referencing the "Current" first LI item.

How can I get around this?

Thanks

Comment: You're just passing the same collection, so unless you get the elements from the DOM again, how can you expect that same old collection of elements to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the set `base.$items` is not a live set, that means even though you change the order of items in dom the set is unaware about it

Try

```
    base.animate = function( ) {
        base.$items.filter(':eq(0)').appendTo(base.$el.find('ul'));
        base.$items = base.$el.find(' ul > li');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you select the relevant items in your init function:

```
base.$items = base.$el.find(' ul > li');
```

base.$items is now a jquery object that doesn't change anymore.
You will have to execute that code every time your timer "ticks".